# Creating DHCP on Virtual Box with windows 2012 server running

Tags: networking, dhcp, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to set up a DHCP server inside a Virtual box running Windows Server 2012, I'm having trouble completing the configuration of the DHCP server.
I've allowed echo requests inside the firewall, created a static IP address as well as attempted to ping another computer within the local group.  This is for a stand alone server.

When I go to complete the configuration it won't allow me to authorize my administrative users credentials. No matter which Administrative user I use it gives me the same error:

Failed to open registry key on target computer to set the status of post configuration task. Error: The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config.

I have tried running the winrm command but it will not allow me to make changes using the CLI. I'm running the CLI as an administrator as well. Even my instructor is currently unsure how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on a RoDC.  A Google search found that it was trying to set an ADSI value which made me question if the issue was that the RoDC was attempting to write to the schema from the registration process.  I ran the post install configuration from another server after adding the DHCP server to it's Server Manager and I received an error that it was already registered but it cleared the flag that the DHCP registration needed to be completed even after closing and reopening Server Manager.